# C++ и ссылки &&

Tags: c++, ссылки, перемещение, копирование

Я бы хотел разобраться в том, для чего именно в `Стандарт C++` были добавлены ссылки `&&`. Какие именно проблемы решает это нововведение?

Да, я знаю, чем отличаются:

```
Object(const Object &_object);
Object(Object && _object);
```

Но я не совсем понимаю, почему нельзя было установить соглашение, что:

```
Object(const Object &_object);// Конструктор копирования.
Object(Object &_object);// Конструктор перемещения.
```

Я встречаю старый код, где ссылки на неконстантное значение используются для сигнализации о перемещении объекта, а ссылки на константное - для сигнализации о копировании.

И меня это сильно сбивает с толка.

Comment: Во-первых, неконстантная ссылка - это не обязательно перемещение. С чего бы это? Во-вторых, неконстантную ссылку нельзя привязать к временному объекту - основному кандидату на перемещение. Ссылка `&&` - это тоже совсем не обязательно перемещение. Это именно ссылка, которую можно привязывать к rvalue.

Comment: Почему нельзя? Очень даже можно. Собственно ранние подходы к реализации семантики перемещения так и делали (тот же `auto_ptr`). Однако стоит заметить, что в таком случае перемещение будет неявным, а неявность, как показывает практика, всегда создает ворох проблем. Также, помимо ссылок, была добавлена возможность перегружать методы классов для rvalue объектов, это тоже может быть полезно.

Comment: *"почему нельзя было установить соглашение, что"* Потому что тогда поведение кода, написанного под C++98, изменилось бы.

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что:

```
Object(Object & _object);
```

это не обязательно перемещение.
И что станет с таким кодом, написанным до C++14? Его поведение изменится.